# Undelete tool for files not in Recycle Bin

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best undelete tool for NTFS/FAT?](https://superuser.com/questions/6810/best-undelete-tool-for-ntfs-fat)

Is there any tool that can help with undeleting a deleted file even though that file does not appear in the Recycle Bin?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows? Yes there are many out there - just Google "recover deleted files" and you should be able to find a bunch- I once used a product called Recover Deleted Files and it worked great - even though you deleted them and emptied your recycle bin they are still on your drive - their are other tools that will actually really delete them but thats another answer

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) in the past, from the same people that have written Defraggler and CCleaner.

there is an option to scan the entire drive for files that have been deleted.